# Did announcing area51 have the impact that was expected?

Tags: discussion, area-51, traffic

I read a comment by Joel a few days back that they were expecting a flood of people to come to area51 once it was publicly announced.

Was it like that or did the activity remain the same?

I think it was the latter, but I don't have the data to support it.

Comment: I get the sense this is a dumb question, but has it been announced somewhere outside the trilogy/meta/related blog sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, traffic is way up. It will continue to go up as it is announced other places as well...

Comment: I got 5 or 6 new followers to my proposal they day of it being posted on the blog.

Comment: What other places? Will it be advertised on random sites? I mean, since it lends itself to non-technical subjects as well the possible places to find an audience is massive

Answer (score 0):

The number of new proposals has spiked a lot, so there must have come a lot of new users. Don't know if the overall activity is up, but it looks like it. Have gotten a lot more votes on my questions as well.